# inflateMenu doesn't work on Toolbar inside CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-inflate, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to assign a menu to a Toolbar which is inside a CollapsingToolbarLayout. These are the xml and Java codes.
The problem is that `inflateMenu` simply does nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/groupPhoto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Java:

```
@InjectView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;
@InjectView(R.id.toolbar_layout)
CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbarLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_details);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbarLayout.setTitle(conversation.getTargetName());
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_backspace_white_24dp);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_conversation_activity);

    ...
}
```

And this is the menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_call"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_phone_24dp"
        android:title="@string/secure_notes"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/secureNote"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pin_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/secure_notes"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/deleteConversation"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/delete_conversation"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/clearHistory"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/clear_history"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/changeBackground"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/change_background"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overiding the **onCreateOptionsMenu()** method like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_conversation_activity, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Hope this is helpful